# Mailgun email template from richtext environment

Tags: node.js, mailgun

We have a concern about sending an email from a rich text environment using Mailgun, where the email includes HTML code. This can indeed happen when the content is copied from a rich text editor; the HTML and inline styles are also copied along with the text.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDT5e.png)

Hello

Thank you for reaching out on this. Happy to assist.

We can't directly assist with code here in support. We can only provide resources and assistance with our system.

The best course of action is to review our API manual which will provide examples of using our template API and acceptable formatting.
https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-templates.html#templates

You can also see some great tips for starting with our templates feature for different situations here.
https://www.mailgun.com/blog/product/getting-started-with-our-email-templates-api/

These may be the most helpful to you as here we go more into detail with example templates that you can use as the base for developing your emails and add in your information.
https://www.mailgun.com/blog/email/transactional-html-email-templates/
https://github.com/mailgun/transactional-email-templates

Please let us know if you have any additional questions.

We did review all APIs
We are using mailgun over a year and we didnt such have problem
mailgun support sucks